# Why is the div inside not load inside the a tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a slideshow inside of an accordion, however when I load the code into the browser, the content inside the `<a>` is beside it, not inside it. Is there any solution to it? The main problem is that when I load the code to debug the `<div class="grid2 transition" id="grid4">` is supposed to be inside of `<a onclick="openUp4()" class="pane1 button" id="pane4">`, however it loads just side by side.

```js
let slideIndex = [1, 1];
let slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  let i;
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex[no] = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex[no] = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex[no] - 1].style.display = "block";
}

function openUp4() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pane4");
  element.classList.toggle("active2")
  if (element.classList.contains("active2")) {
    // document.getElementById("grid2").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("grid4").style.opacity = 1;
  } else {
    // document.getElementById("grid2").style.visibility = "hidden";   
    document.getElementById("grid4").style.opacity = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.pane1 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active2 {
  height: fit-content;
}

.grid2 {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0rem;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  height: inherit;
  justify-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blacktitle {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #191919;
  height: 70px;
  width: 50%;
  left: -20px;
  top: -45px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 21px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}

.mySlides1 {
  display: none
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

video {
  max-width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 40%;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto auto auto;
}

.videocontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 533.333px;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a grey background color */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="openUp4()" class="pane1 button" id="pane4">
  <div class="blacktitle">
    Concerts
  </div>
  <div class="grid2 transition" id="grid4">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="Concerts/a03c3e49-cdff-4382-87c1-b473de9f6447.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides1">
        <img src="Concerts/IMG_6847.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides1 videocontainer">
        <video controls preload="metadata">
                      <source src="Concerts/IMG_5888.mov" type="video/mp4" style="width:100%">
                      </video>
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You have anchors nested inside of anchors. That is invalid html.

Comment: Because you have a <a> in your <a>, thats not allowed (your prev/next)

Comment: in the code posted you have a script issue (TypeError: x[(slideIndex[no] - 1)] is undefined") could you please fix it to build a minimum reproducible sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I'm having a little trouble understanding the question, but from your code, 2 things pop up immediately:

The first is the usage of `<div>` inside `<a>`. You should never use a block element (like `div`, `h1`, `p`, etc) inside an inline element (like `a`,`span`,`strong`, etc). Some browsers *might* be able to parse it but this is definitely invalid HTML.

A solution to that would be to replace the `<div>` elements inside the anchor tag with `<span>` instead, and add a `display:block` CSS rule to the relevant `<span>` tags so they mimic how the `<div>` looks like.

The second issue is around this line:

```
x[slideIndex[no] - 1].style.display = "block";
```

`x[slideIndex[no] - 1]` does not always return an element, so you cannot assume you can access its style property. A safer way to do it would be this:

```
// Get the element first
const el = x[slideIndex[no] - 1];

// If it exists, *then* access and mutate its properties.
if(el) el.style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it this works:

```
    <div class="pagebody">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flex-container">
<div class="pane1 button" id="pane4">
                <span onclick="openUp4()" class="blacktitle">
                    Concerts
                </span>
                <span class="grid2 transition" id="grid4">
                <span class="slideshow-container">
                    <span class="mySlides1">
                      <div style="width: 400px; height: 533px; background-color:"></div>
                    </span>
                  
                    <span class="mySlides1">
                      <div style="width: 400px; height: 533px; background-color: green"></div>
                    </span>
                  
                    <span class="mySlides1">
                      <div style="width: 400px; height: 533px; background-color: blue"></div>
                    </span>
                  
                    <button class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
                    <button class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
                </span>
                </span>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.blacktitle:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
}
.blacktitle {
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #191919;
    height: 70px;
    width: 50%;
    left: -20px;
    top: -45px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 21px;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.transition {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.grid2 {
    display: grid;
    gap: 0rem;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    height: inherit;
    justify-content: center;
    place-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.active2 {
    height: 600px;
}
.pane1 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.container {
    padding: 0px 60px 60px 60px;
    background-color: #191919;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;    }
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: top;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.pagebody {
    background-color: #191919;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.mySlides1 {display: none; overflow: hidden;}
img {vertical-align: middle; max-width: 400px; box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2); border-radius: 5px;}

video {max-width: 400px; box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2); border-radius: 5px; margin-top: 40%;}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto auto auto;
}
.videocontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 533.333px;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  background:none;
  border:none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a grey background color */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```
          function openUp4(){
            var element = document.getElementById("pane4");
            element.classList.toggle("active2")
            if (element.classList.contains("active2")) {
                // document.getElementById("grid2").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("grid4").style.opacity = 1;
                } else {
                // document.getElementById("grid2").style.visibility = "hidden";   
                document.getElementById("grid4").style.opacity = 0;  
             }  
          }
let slideIndex = [1,1];
let slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}
function showSlides(n, no) {
  let i;
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
            const el = x[slideIndex[no] - 1];

if(el){el.style.display = "block";}
}  
}
```